# How to get vpc id using another variable in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am getting vpc id from vpc module like below:

```
    vpc_id = module.vpcName.vpc_id
```

But I want to get vpcName from vars.tf. I want someting like below but of course it doesn't work. I researched but couldn't find any example.

```
    variable "name" {
        description = "VPC Name"
        type = string
        default = "vpcName"
    }

    vpc_id = "module.${var.name}.vpc_id"
```

Is there any way to achive this?

Comment: What are the outputs in `vpcName` module?

Comment: To elaborate: you would need to transform the output of each `module` declaration into a Map. You would actually have that structure automatically if your module declarations were iterated instead of individual.

Comment: You can't name a module based on a variable, so why do you need to reference the module's name based on a variable? In your code, `variable "name"` the name is hard-coded, it's always going to be `name`. So to get the ID it should always be `module.name.vpc_id`